# DOM creates XML with invalid characters

Tags: java, dom

I am using a DOM/Transformer pattern to create XML documents. Sometimes the source will contain invalid characters (like '\u0002'). I anticipated that, but I expected that there would be a DOMException assembling the Document or a TransformerException transforming to a Result. Instead the Result contains the invalid XML characters.

There must be a way to prevent the Document from creating a XML doc that it cannot parse itself. The Document normalizeDocument() looked promising but the default DOMConfiguration does not support the "well-formed" parameter.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

\u0002 is a unicode representation of an empty character so technically it is not invalid. You just have to ignore it when outputing it to the XML file.